# SharePoint 2010 deployment scenario for Intranet + HR records

Tags: server-farm, farm-solution

We are planning on using SharePoint 2010 to host our Intranet and want to use it as an electronic document management system for personnel records too. What deployment scenario would be best for us?

We have 5000 users who access the existing Intranet, primarily to view information rather than add or edit content. We would like to use the SharePoint platform to develop in-house applications too. The main SharePoint services we would like to use is the Web Content Management System, Excel services and Search services, although we would like to keep our options open and may decide to use other services such as Access services for example.

With regard to the electronic document management system the files will be PDFs and there will be any number of documents for all of our 5000 employees. It's difficult to estimate the size of the documents, however I would roughly estimate an average of 100kb per document.

Thanks

Comment: How many users? Which SharePoint services do you need? Do you plan to use this platform for future applications? What format are the documents? How many are there? How large are they (per document, total size)?

Comment: @shufler Many thanks for the response, I've updated the question. I hope I have answered all your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there are no precise matches between requirements and actual deployments to learn from - I'd like to recommend a few Microsoft case studies here: [IT Showcase resources for SharePoint Server 2010.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2012/01/23/how-does-microsoft-it-do-it-check-out-these-it-showcase-resources-for-sharepoint-server-2010.aspx)
These contain examples related to HR, ECM, Document Management, etc.

Comment: another large source of case studies are at the Microsoft Case Study site here - http://www.microsoft.com/casestudies/